# in R how can I change the value of a character string based on a condition for each row of a data frame

Tags: r, replace

I have a data frame:

```
a = c(2, 3, 5, 4) 
b = as.character(c("dogs are loving", "cats are the best", "we prefer cats", "dogs are sweet"))
df = data.frame(a, b)
print(df)

 a         b
 2   dogs are loving
 3   cats are the best
 5   we prefer cats
 4   dogs are sweet
```

I want to change df$b so that it becomes:

```
 a     b
 2   dogs are loving
 3   cats
 5   cats
 4   dogs are sweet
```

I know I can use grepl to find out if the character cell contains the word cats...

```
grepl("cats", df$b, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

... But I don't know how to use this to then change the character cell to "cats."

Comment: Please review the answers below and mark one correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
df$b <- as.character(df$b)
df$b[grepl('cats', df$b)] <- 'cats'
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tim Biegeleisen !

Answer (score 4):

```
df = data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors = F)

df$b[grepl('cats', df$b)] <- 'cats'
```

`grepl('cats', df$b)` creates a logical vector, and you can use that to conditionally apply the change.

I had forgotten to include the `stringsAsFactors = F` originally. Using this command will get rid of a lot of headaches, and I wish it was the default.

Comment: Because `df$b` is actually a factor variable, your code will cause `NA`s to be inserted instead of `'cats`'.

Comment: ah yes, thank you. I actually added `stringsAsFactors = F` in the creation of the dataframe, but forgot to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
df$b <- as.character(df$b)
df$b <- gsub(".*cats.*", "cats", df$b)
```

which is faster when compared to `df$b[grepl('cats', df$b)] <- 'cats'` when I checked with `microbenchmark`

```
> microbenchmark(df$b <- gsub(".*cats.*", "cats", df$b), df$b[grepl('cats', df$b)] <- 'cats', times=10000L)
Unit: microseconds
                                   expr    min     lq     mean median      uq      max
 df$b <- gsub(".*cats.*", "cats", df$b) 36.870 38.771 52.04216 39.911 59.2965 2040.421
    df$b[grepl("cats", df$b)] <- "cats" 40.291 42.953 59.55412 44.473 66.8990 3087.998
 neval
 10000
 10000
```

Comment: I would encourage you to increase the size of your benchmark -- it's not clear how meaningful a benchmark is when you're operating over a data frame with 4 rows. When I ran on a data frame with 40,000 rows, the gsub solution took about twice as long as the grepl approach.

Comment: Most interesting. I don't have a big data set to try it on, so I substituted it with more evals on `microbenchmark`. It will be interesting to know at what size of dataframe `grepl` becomes faster than `gsub`.

Comment: I just used `big.df <- df[rep(1:4, 10000),]`.

Comment: or `bigger.df <- data.frame(a=1:1e5, b=sample(c('cats are the best', 'dogs'), 1e5, replace=T))`

Comment: Why didn't I think of dummying. Anyway, apparently big data is not needed, indeed `gsub` is consistently slower than `grepl` once data frame has as few as 20 rows in it.